# what Openstack version is better to deploye in vmware Virtualization

Tags: openstack

We have one existing vmware virtualization contains 4 host, each host contains nearly 6vms, Now we are planning to deploy Open stack, The thing which Open stack version is good to deploy in VM, i have installed Centos 7 on VM.

I have to confirm which version of open stack is good for real time environment.

If anyone knows pls suggest version, and installation URl it will much better understanding to me,

Answer (score 0):

Get started with devstack which is easier to install as you just have to run one script(stack.sh) and it will deploy all the clients on same machine. You can use that to practice creating VMs, making security groups and assigning floating ip to the vms. After that try to configure on a multinode architecture and I would suggest that you get a Ravello account (https://www.ravellosystems.com/) for that instead of using your own servers. This link might help you in configuration (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E54155/archover.html#scrolltoc). 
Search "openstack multinode deployment" on google. You will have plenty of links.

Comment: Also, Juno is the one I have used..you can try kilo